# Mobile Emulation in Dev Tool of the Chrome doesn't properly understand css media query

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I works with the site (http://kursy.ru.com/) to make it responsive.
And I found that in my Chrome V51 the Dev Tool doesn't work properly when it open as "toggle device toolbar"!

Please see the both of screens below.

http://prnt.sc/bn2rz9

http://prnt.sc/bn2vut

(But similar toolbar works properly in Firefox.)

Does anybody have the same problem?

Of course, the following tag is added to `<head>` section!
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! It's my carelessness! I just mad mistake, and wrote `initial-scale=0` ))
It should be `initial-scale=1.0`

Have nohting) more to say.